# Composer terminated on update

Tags: symfony, composer-php

```
$ php composer.phar update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Terminated
```

Composer terminated when I try to update dependencies in my symfony2 application. Where can be problem?

**Edit**

I tried to run `composer diag` and output was:

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking composer.json:

  [ErrorException]
  Undefined index: require-dev
```

But there is no line "require-dev" in my composer.json.

Comment: can we see your composer.json?

Comment: here http://pastie.org/8574457

Comment: If you are not a bit more specific, the problem could be anywhere. Was the internet connection lost during update? Is there maybe a log somewhere with more information? Have you tried it again after a few minutes/one hour/one day?

You see that you don't really give any information about your research whatsoever, which leaves us here nothing but do a wild ass guess.

Comment: I tried it again in the next day an it terminated again. I try to do it in the hosting, but in my local computer it's work fine. Internet connection is ok. I don't know where can be problem so I can't be more specific because I don't know what information can be usefull for solve this problem.

Comment: `composer update -vvv` is more verbose. `composer diag` shows if every basic operation works. Note that Composer is not really meant to download dependencies on production machines. The usual workflow should call `composer install` before sending all the files to the production machine.